# Highcharts create space for negative value

Tags: highcharts

Creating Pie chart using highcharts library but it creates empty space between slice for negative value.

I would like to remove that empty space and want to show negative value as 0.0.

Following is my code..

```
  [http://jsfiddle.net/mukeshkumartech/xnxL3adL/][1]
```

You can see with this code that data is not displaying for "Firefox" as 0.0 without creating sapce.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare you data before passing it to the chart constructor just like this:

```
  data: [
    ['Firefox', -45.089],
    ['IE', 26.8], 
            ['Chrome:', -10],
    ['Safari', 8.5],
    ['Opera', 6.298],
    ['Others', 0.7]
  ].map(function(pointArr) {

    var newPoint = {
        name: pointArr[0]
      },
      value = pointArr[1];
    if (value < 0) {
      newPoint.y = 0;
      newPoint.negY = value;
    } else {
      newPoint.y = value
    }
    return newPoint;
  })
```

If the value is negative than I use `0` as the `y` property and save the original value in the `negY` property to use it later in the `dataLabels.formater`:

```
    dataLabels: {
      enabled: true,
      formatter: function() {
        console.log(this);
        var point = this.point;
        return this.key + " - value: " + (point.negY ? point.negY : point.y);
      }
    }
```

**Live working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/6u7Lzfu9/

**API reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pie.dataLabels.formatter